# escribir en dos input

Tags: html5

tengo dos input en un mismo formulario uno se llama municipio y el otro 
municipio_inm y lo que quiero es que al momento de escribir en el input municipio se escriba en muncipio_inm o se pase ese valor , solo si el valor de municipio si lo cambio en municipio_inm que no se cambie el de municipio.

```
     <input name="municipio"  class="form-control" type="text" 
      id="municipio" placeholder="Escriba el Municipio" required>


     <input name="municipio_inm" class="form-control"  size="35" type="text" 
     id="municipio_inm" placeholder="Escriba el municipio del inmueble" 
     required onkeypress="document.forms.m_form_1.municipio.value = 
     this.value">
```

Comment: Necesitas hacerlo en javascript / jQuery.  Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: , no lo intente en javascript solo intente colocandolo asi onkeypress="document.forms.m_form_1.municipio.value = 
     this.value"

Answer (score 2):

Con javascript puedes utilizar el evento `oninput` para detectar cambios en tú input e ir actualizando el valor de tú otro input.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>
                Prueba Input
            </title>
        </meta>
    </head>
</html>
<body>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <input class="form-control" id="municipio" name="municipio" oninput="actualizarValorMunicipioInm()" placeholder="Escriba el Municipio" required="" size="35" type="text">
            <input class="form-control" id="municipio_inm" name="municipio_inm" placeholder="Escriba el municipio del inmueble" required="" size="35" type="text">
            </input>
        </input>
    </div>
    <script>
        function actualizarValorMunicipioInm() {
   let municipio = document.getElementById("municipio").value;
   //Se actualiza en municipio inm
   document.getElementById("municipio_inm").value = municipio;
  }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo queres hacer con javascript sobre tu html, deberias buscar el elemento,

```
document.getElementById('municipio')
```

y luego cambiamos tu evento `onkeypress` por `onkeyup` para copiar el valor luego de que se grave en el primer input

quedaria algo asi

```
<input name="municipio"  class="form-control" type="text" 
      id="municipio" placeholder="Escriba el Municipio" required>    

<input name="municipio_inm" class="form-control"  size="35" type="text" 
     id="municipio_inm" placeholder="Escriba el municipio del inmueble" 
     required onkeyup="document.getElementById('municipio').value = this.value">
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues yo te lo pongo en jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#municipio').change(function(){
  valor=$(this).val();
    $('#municipio_inm').val(valor);
  })
})
```

Lo que hace es coger el valor del input con id municipio y pasarselo al input con id municipio_inm. No pasa el valor de municipio_inm a municipio.

Debes, por supuesto, agregar la biblioteca de jquery. Si no la tienes puedes usar el cdn de Google:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

El script, si no tienes un archivo para los js, ponlo al pie de todas las páginas donde quieras realizar esta acción.

Aquí la demostración: https://jsfiddle.net/Emerita/16xmujvp/2/